# FreeBSD 10.0-RELEASE: No lagg0 after reboot

Tags: networking, freebsd, bonding

I have a server running Freebsd 10.0-RELEASE. I'm trying to create bridge interface with three participant interfaces, ix0, ix1 and lagg0. Lagg0 is virtual interface made from ix2 and ix3. My problem is that lagg0 is not created on boot. I can create it after the boot and it automatically takes over ix2 and ix3. After that I can manually add it to the bridge0.

I have this in my /etc/rc.conf:

```
if_lagg_load="YES"
ifconfig_ix0="mtu 9000 UP" 
ifconfig_ix1="mtu 9000 UP"
ifconfig_ix2="mtu 9000 UP"
ifconfig_ix3="mtu 9000 UP"
cloned_interfaces="lagg0"
ifconfig_lagg0="laggproto roundrobin laggport ix2 laggport ix3 up"
cloned_interfaces="bridge0"
ifconfig_bridge0="addm ix0 addm ix1 addm lagg0 up"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that are wrong with this configuration. First of all, you have defined the cloned_interfaces variable twice. The second one will be overriding the first. You should use something like

```
cloned_interfaces="lagg0 bridge0"
```

The other thing is a minor note like arved said. if_lagg_load="YES" belongs to /boot/loader.conf. However, personally, I prefer using the kld_list variable in /etc/rc.conf for performance reasons:

```
kld_list="if_lagg"
```

Answer (score 0):

`if_lagg_load="Yes"`

belongs into /boot/loader.conf